# Assign the result of measuring a for loop with /usr/bin/time in a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, time

I need to execute a curl command inside a for loop multiple times, and get the average time it took to execute a single curl. This is what I have:

```
while read query; do
  TIMEFORMAT=%R; time for i in {1..3}; do curl -s -w '\n' -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode query='${query}' ${nginx_url} > /dev/null; done
done < queries.txt
```

This prints the number of seconds in stdout, but I need to assign that number to a variable to divide it by 3 in order to get the average.

I have tested with:

```
realtime=$(time -f "%E" for i in {1..3} ..etc..)
realtime=`time -f "%E" for i in {1..3} ..etc..`
```

But this gives syntax error `./test-suite.sh: line 23: syntax error near unexpected token`do'.

I have also tested with:

```
realtime=$(bash -c "TIMEFORMAT=%R; time for i in {1..3} ..etc..")
realtime=$(bash -c "time -f "%E" for i in {1..3} ..etc..")
realtime=$(bash -c "TIMEFORMAT=%R; time for i in {1..3} do ..etc.. ; done; echo $realtime")
```

All of them bear no results. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: You aren't using `/usr/bin/time`. You're using bash's `time` keyword.

Comment: Had the same issues with /usr/bin/time, forgot to add that,but thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, I have to enclose the command into parenthesis as well,

```
mytime=$(time (for i in {1..3}; do curl -s -w '\n' -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode query='select distinct ?Concept where {[] a ?Concept} LIMIT 100' http://143.233.226.61:443/sparql > /dev/null; done) 2>&1 1>/dev/null)
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be (slightly modified, since I don't have your curl/HTTP setup):

```
$ t=$(TIMEFORMAT=%R bash -c 'time for i in {1..3}; do sleep $((RANDOM % 5)); done' 2>&1)
$ avg=$(bc <<< "scale=3; $t/3")
$ echo $avg # YMMV
2.667
```

Since `time` is a bash built-in, we need to place the `stderr` redirection "outside" of the time call; that's why I wrapped the main part with `bash -c ...`.

You don't need to set TIMEFORMAT every time through the loop; just put it in the environment for the call to bash/time.

Note that shell arithmetic is integer-based, so for floating-point values, use something like `bc`. My `time` output had 3 decimal places, so that's what I asked `bc` for as well.